# How to transpile ES6 to ES5 for 3rd party libs?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I have a webpack setup that works almost fine, but I see an error that UglifyJS emits when I import some 3rd party libs that are written in ES6. Here is an example from `node-postgres`:

```
module.exports = {
  prepareValue: function prepareValueWrapper (value) {
    // this ensures that extra arguments do not get passed into prepareValue
    // by accident, eg: from calling values.map(utils.prepareValue)
    return prepareValue(value)
  },
  normalizeQueryConfig,
  postgresMd5PasswordHash,
  md5
}
```

Here is the how it should look in ES5:

```
module.exports = {
  prepareValue: function prepareValueWrapper (value) {
    // this ensures that extra arguments do not get passed into prepareValue
    // by accident, eg: from calling values.map(utils.prepareValue)
    return prepareValue(value)
  },
  normalizeQueryConfig: normalizeQueryConfig,
  postgresMd5PasswordHash: postgresMd5PasswordHash,
  md5: md5
}
```

When the original code is processed by UglifyJS, I see this error:

> ERROR in proxy.js from UglifyJs
>
> Unexpected token: punc (,) [proxy.js:382,22]

Which points to the code from above.

As I am compiling a TypeScript project, I suspect I need to process 3rd party libs code through some transpiler inside Webpack flow to convert them to ES5 before bundling.

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

const root = (dir) => {
    return path.resolve(__dirname, dir);
};

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.ts',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
        modules: [root('node_modules'), root('src')]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'proxy.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
    },
    target: 'node'
};
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [uglify-es](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/tree/harmony) to minify your ES6 code, or use Babel with [ES2015 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/) to transpile the code to ES5.

Comment: If you'll notice, the question was "for 3rd party libs".